# Exception Value field is blank when throwing custom exceptions in django

Tags: python, django, exception

I have custom exceptions in my django project that look like this:

```
class CustomFooError(Exception):

    def __init__(self, msg="Something went wrong with Foo."):
        self.msg = msg

    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.msg)
```

At various points in my code I will raise exceptions like this:

```
raise CustomFooError("Things are going badly")
```

When Django catches these errors, in debug mode I get django's standard pretty stack-trace page.  But I never see my error messages -- "Things are going badly" never shows up in the debug error page.

It seems they should show up as the `Exception Value` on the error page.  I walked back through the django source far enough to find out that this is the `value` field from `sys.exc_info()` which is consistently tersely documented as "[the exception's] associated value or the second argument to raise, which is always a class instance if the exception type is a class object."  Unfortunately, I don't know what to do with this information.

So my question is: How should I be writing and raising my custom exceptions to get more useful data to show up in places like the django error screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use `super` and let the constructor of `Exception` handle assigning the `msg` attribute:

```
class CustomFooError(Exception):

    def __init__(self, msg=None):
        if msg is None:
            msg = 'Something went wrong with Foo.'
        super(CustomFooError, self).__init__(msg)
```

I just tested this from within a Django environment and it correctly displayed the message I passed to the exception constructor or the default one if None was passed.

Answer (score 1):

@AdmiralNemo is right: let the base class do the work.

But to dig into your code a little deeper, the problem is that you don't tie into the Exception implementation at all.  Exception(s) stores s in the .message attribute, not .msg.  It also stores it as (s,) in the .args attribute.  Your code doesn't set either of these attributes, which is probably why Django can't find a message to display.

Also, your `__str__` method is odd.  It should return `self.msg`, not `repr(self.msg)`, which would add quotes around the string, and potentially escapes inside the text.

Comment: Thanks.  I borrowed the exception code from some library figuring they knew more about subclassing Exception than I do.